# USD670286 - Do glossy lines on a surface count in a design patent?

Tags: design-patent, usd670286

This patent has been cited as an example of patenting a rounded rectangle, as the solid lines appear to form only a rounded rectangular frontal shape.

However, do the "glossy" shading lines on the front surface also count?  In other words, is this actually a patent for a shiny flat rounded rectangular front?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the glossy surface is part of the claimed design. As is the radius of the curved corners, the ratio of length to height, the thickness, the curve of the back and everything else drawn in solid lines.